# One-to-many hibernate, saving null values

Tags: spring, hibernate, jstl

This is my Code for Jsp to iterate through the list

```
<c:forEach items="${location.fEvents}" var="item" varStatus="loop">
                <tr><td><form:input path="fEvents[${loop.index}].hostName" size="30" maxlength="200"/></td>
                <td><form:input path="fEvents[${loop.index}].directory" size="30" maxlength="200"/></td>
                <td><form:input path="fEvents[${loop.index}].userName" size="20" maxlength="20"/></td>
                <td><form:input path="fEvents[${loop.index}].password" size="20" maxlength="20"/></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
```

My code in controller:

```
while (location.getfEvents().size() < 3) {
            FtpScanEvents f = new FtpScanEvents();
            f.setLocation(location);
            location.getfEvents().add(f);
        }
```

whenever there is new entry, My jsp displays three empty rows, If user enters data in first row, It should save only that to database. But, my code is saving the other two empty rows as null to database. This is because I am using spring binding and iterating the list to show the values (JSP Code).

Any suggestion to avoid this!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it is something to do with my code to save the data!

Comment: if there is a possibility of getting the index from JSP to controller, then It will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the fields for null and empty before inserting in the database.